# Constant page directive with parameter

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I am trying to use a constant for a page directive

```
@page "/printenv/"
@page "/printenv/{TreeId:long}"
```

while using the RouteAttribute for "/printenv" works like this:

```
@attribute [RouteAttribute(Href)] 
@page "/printenv/{TreeId:long}"
            
@code {

  public const string Href = $"/{PageNav.PrintEnv}"; 
             
  [Parameter]
  public long TreeId { get; set; }

}
        
public static class PageNav
{
   public const string PrintEnv= "printenv";
}
```

I am unable to find a way to use a constant for the parameter.
Is there a way i can use a constant and the parameter TreeId ?

Comment: No. The attribute is set at compile time, the static class `PageNav` and thus the `const` is set at runtime.